# How do I do an `if user_signed_in?` check on an action that triggers a JS toggle?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I use Devise, and so in my views whenever I want to hide something from a non-signed-in user, I just  add a quick:

`<% if user_signed_in? %>` around the portion of the view and voila.

The issue is now, I have a button that triggers a toggle JS action on the page.

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="togglesidebar" class="pull-right">
     <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-child"></i> Submit News</button>
</div>
```

This is the JS:

```
var ready;
ready = function() {

    // This is the Sidebar toggle functionality
    var toggleSidebar = $("#togglesidebar");
    var primary = $("#primary");
    var secondary = $("#secondary");

    toggleSidebar.on("click", function(){

        if(primary.hasClass("col-sm-9")){
            primary.removeClass("col-sm-9");
            primary.addClass("col-sm-12");
            secondary.css('display', 'none');
        }
        else {
            primary.removeClass("col-sm-12");
            primary.addClass("col-sm-9");
            secondary.css('display', 'inline-block');
        }
    });
};

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

What I want to happen is, if the current_user is not logged in, they should get redirected to a 'please login' modal before they that Sidebar is toggled.

Then upon successful login, it should then redirect them back to that same page with the Sidebar toggled.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could set a js variable using erb like this:

```
var user_signed_in = <%= user_signed_in? %>
```

and then use that variable inside of your js to determine if you should display the modal, etc.

Comment: Where would I do the assignment? In my view or in my JS?

Comment: In the application layout, I know that putting JS right in the view is not the best practice, but the javascript assets once compiled and in production shouldn't depend on the state of the request, so I guess this is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

You can mix JS and Rails, directly in view, like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var ready;
  ready = function() {

      // This is the Sidebar toggle functionality
      var toggleSidebar = $("#togglesidebar");
      var primary = $("#primary");
      var secondary = $("#secondary");

      toggleSidebar.on("click", function(){

      <% if user_signed_in? %>

          if(primary.hasClass("col-sm-9")){
              primary.removeClass("col-sm-9");
              primary.addClass("col-sm-12");
              secondary.css('display', 'none');
          }
          else {
            primary.removeClass("col-sm-12");
              primary.addClass("col-sm-9");
              secondary.css('display', 'inline-block');
          }

      <% else %>

        window.location.replace("<%= escape_javascript(login_path) %>");

      <% end %>

      });
  };

  $(document).ready(ready);
  $(document).on('page:load', ready);
</script>
```

Comment: Definitely don't like the idea of putting JS right in my view.

Comment: So you can add an hidden field anywhere in your page (like `<%= hidden_field_tag :user_signed_in, user_signed_in?.inspect, :id => 'user_signed_in' %>`), then get its value in JS, like `if ($('#user_sign_in') == 'true')`.